# c# linq fill not mapping properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I am using the Entities Framework Code First and I have two entities:

```
public class Product 
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }     
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int ProductCategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
} 

public class ProductStorage
{
  [Key]
  public int ProductId { get; set; }


  [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
  public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

  public int Quantity { get; set; }

}
```

I can't seem to get `Product` list filled with the `Quantity` property.

I tried

```
from pr in repository.Query<Product>()
   join st in repository.Query<ProductStorage>() on pr.ProductID equals st.Quantity
   select new Product()
   {
       ProductID = pr.ProductID,
        ....
       Quantity = st.Quantity

   };
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Join` is done `On` the wrong field, try this:

```
from pr in repository.Query<Product>()
join st in repository.Query<ProductStorage>() on pr.ProductID equals st.ProductID 
select new Product()
   {
   ProductID = pr.ProductID,
        ....
   Quantity = st.Quantity
   };
```

But, since both `ProductStorage` and `Product` share the `ProductId` field, that implies you can have them related in a one-to-one relationship, something like:

```
public class Product 
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }     
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int ProductCategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductStorage Storage { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int Quantity { get { return this.Storage.Quantity; }  }
}
```